# Why does my user control pageLoad function not fire on some of my ASP.net pages?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I'm working on an ASP.net application.

I had a problem with a user control I'd designed called `LocationSelector`.  It worked great, but I couldn't use it within an ASP:UpdatePanel.  I learned, by browsing SO, that I needed to put my in-line javascript in an external file and register it with `ScriptManager` so that there are no `Response.Write` calls in the Javascript.

Next, I discovered that the control worked at first, but when I enclosed it within the ASP:UpdatePanel, it would stop functioning after the first AJAX postback.  I read that to fix that, I needed to replace my `$(document).ready` call with `function pageLoad()` which is automatically executed with each ASP.net page load.

Several of my pages in my ASP.net application work fine (and I was really impressed with how well the framework seemed to drive the application).  However, to my dismay, I discovered that my `LocationSelector` control no longer works *at all* on three of my pages.  The HTML renders, but the pageLoad (which uses jQuery to bind events on control elements) does not fire.

I verified this but putting `alert('pageLoad');` as the first line of my `pageLoad` function.  On the pages that work, I see the alert.  On the pages that don't work, I never see the alert, even on the initial page load.

What kind of problem could be causing the `pageLoad` function on my user control `LocationSelector` to execute on some pages, but not others?

Comment: Are there script errors on those pages?  Are things declared the same?  Do the pages that do not work all have something in common or similar format/template that makes them different from the working pages?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem, but I still don't know what the solution is.

My user control `Location Selector` is in the relative directory `~/Controls`.  I register the scripts using the following code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this, typeof(LocationSelector), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Controls/LocationSelector.js");
```

The problem is with the relative path to the JavaScript file Controls/LocationSelector.js.

The pages that work with this code are all in the root directory of the ASP.net application.  The pages that don't work are in subdirectories.

Comment: I think you answered your own question... change the code to register `"~/Controls/LocationSelector.js"`. If for some reason ScriptManager doesn't work with relative paths, use `ResolveUrl` function (a member of `Control`).